# How to build a dll from multiple projects

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I have a project A.vcxproj and a solution A.sln that consists of two projects b.vcxproj and c.vcxproj. Now A.sln builds into a .exe file. I need to create a dll file out this setup. For that I had opened another new project called D.sln that builds a dll. Now I need to add the original projects into it. Should I just add the A.vcxproj or do I need to add both b.vcxproj and c.vcxproj instead of A.vcxproj?

Answer (score 0):

Each project produces *something*. Here, the two contributions to the EXE will be static libraries. The new DLL will also be built from these static libraries, so it needs those projects. The new DLL does *not* need `int main()` so it doesn't need `A.vcxproj`.

Comment: Thanks, My real scenario actually consists of 52 projects So I will have to individually add each of those projects. Will adding the .vcxproj files be enough, or do I need to add the .cpp and .h files of the projects?

Comment: Well, the far easier solution is to add `D.vcxproj` to `A.sln`. I don't know why you came up with a second solution.

Comment: I downloaded the source code folder of a Media Player that had a solution file that consisted of all those 52 projects. But the solution was building into a .exe. I need a .dll instead. All material online suggested opening a new project that compiles as a dll which would be my D.vcxproj. So are you suggesting that adding D.vcxproj to the downloaded solution  and building the solution will create a dll file of the Media Player?

Comment: @khl: Well, there are the minor details of setting the output type of the new D.vcxproj to DLL, adding at least one file, and implementing `DllMain`. And figuring out which functions to export from your DLL, of course.